Why does clicking an image URL not work to open it in browser?
I embedded this link https://i.sstatic.net/5AFpedHO.jpg in a post outside Stack Exchange. The URL had been created by uploading an image in a post in Stack Exchange.
When I click the link in the post to open the web page in a new tab of my Google Chrome browser, I get an error:



But when I refresh the webpage, I can access the webpage.
Why was the error in the first attempt?
How can I make it work at the first attempt?

Short version would be that hotlinking was disabled with the new image hosting. I'd guess the image loaded on its own (not hotlinked), and you're getting it off the cache. Basically you can't.
